# nested if statement within a for loop doesn't work

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a nested if statement within a for loop but the first if statement seems not to be progressing onto the rest of the for loop.

```
for i, x in enumerate(S[start:-1], start):
    if i > max(sma_period1, sma_period2, sma_period3):
        j = i-start
        
        if ma1[i] == x:
            w[j+1] = w[j]
            cash[j+1] = cash[j]

        if ma1[i] < x: 
            w[j+1] = cash[j]/x  + w[j]
            cash[j+1] = 0

        if ma1[i] > x:
            cash[j+1] = w[j]*x + cash[j]
            w[j+1] = 0

tf_strategy_ma1 = [a*b for a,b in zip(w,S[start:])]+ cash
```

Sorry if this is a very basic question,  I am new to coding and completely stuck.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: if its not getting in you need to get an idea of what the test is seeing.   the max() statement as currently show in in your post  does not vary each time through the loop and can be calculated and assigned a variable before entering the loop.   I would do that,  print that value then print the I value on each iteration.   that will give you an idea how the loop is behaving.

Comment: Why have used S[start:-1] in enumerate. Never seen something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some debug pointers for a situation like this:

1. you need to get an idea of what the test is seeing.
2. the max() statement as currently show in in your post does not vary each time through the loop and can be calculated and assigned a variable before entering the loop.
3. I would do that, print that value then print the I value on each iteration. that will give you an idea how the loop is behaving.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. Thank you very much. I did in fact follow your advice.